# HttpPostedFile return null value?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have a form sends POST data to Action, and a Model has HttpPostedFile field, but when I send the Form data to Action I just get the null value HttpPostedFile Field
.

**This is my Model:**

```
public class MemberModel
{
    [DisplayName("Member Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Telephone / Mobile Number")]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Upload File")]
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFile ImageFile { get; set; }
}
```

**This is my Action:**

```
public ActionResult ContactForm(MemberModel membervalues)
    {
        //Use Namespace called :  System.IO
        string FileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(membervalues.ImageFile.FileName);

        //To Get File Extension
        string FileExtension = Path.GetExtension(membervalues.ImageFile.FileName);

        //Add Current Date To Attached File Name
        FileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "-" + FileName.Trim() + FileExtension;

        //Get Upload path from Web.Config file AppSettings.
        string UploadPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserImagePath"].ToString();

        //Its Create complete path to store in server.
        membervalues.ImagePath = UploadPath + FileName;

        //To copy and save file into server.
        membervalues.ImageFile.SaveAs(membervalues.ImagePath);

        //To save Club Member Contact Form Detail to database table.


        var db = new ClubMemberDataClassesDataContext();

        tblMember _member = new tblMember();

        _member.ImagePath = membervalues.ImagePath;
        _member.MemberName = membervalues.Name;
        _member.PhoneNumber = membervalues.PhoneNumber;

        db.tblMembers.InsertOnSubmit(_member);
        db.SubmitChanges();
        return View();
    }
```

**This is my Form View:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImagePath, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="file" name="ImageFile" required />
    </div>
</div>
```

**And this result while I'm trying upload Image File:** 
[image]

Comment: I change the HttpPostedFile by HttpPostedFileBase, the program is worked. But I don't know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [HttpPostedFileBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httppostedfilebase?view=netframework-4.8) instead of `HttpPostedFile`

**Remark**

> The HttpPostedFileBase class is an abstract class that contains the
>   same members as the HttpPostedFile class. The HttpPostedFileBase class
>   lets you create derived classes that are like the HttpPostedFile
>   class, but **that you can customize and that work outside the ASP.NET pipeline**

Besides, `HttpPostedFile` is sealed class so you cannot create & bind instant

```
public sealed class HttpPostedFile
```

While `HttpPostedFileBase` is abstract class.

```
public abstract class HttpPostedFileBase
```